# Show that if for arbitrary $f: X \rightarrow Y$, there exists $U \subseteq Y$ such that $f\big(f^{-1}(U)\big) ≠ U$, then $f$ is not surjective

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I would like to prove following

> **Proposition 1.** Define arbitrary $f: X \rightarrow Y$. If exists $U \subseteq Y$ such that $f\big(f^{-1}(U)\big) ≠ U$, then $f$ is not surjective.

Notes on notation:

1. $f(U)$ denotes *forward image*, i.e

$$f(U) = \big\{f(x) \mid x \in U\big\}$$

1. $f^{-1}(U)$ denotes *backward image*, i.e

$$f^{-1}(U) = \big\{ x \in \text{Dom}(f) \mid f(x) \in U\big\}$$

My attempt:

> **Lemma 1.** For arbitrary $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and arbitrary $U \subseteq Y$,  $f\big(f^{-1}(U)\big) \subseteq U$

Take some $y \in f\big(f^{-1}(U)\big)$. Then exists $x \in f^{-1}(U)$ such that $f(x) = y$. Since $x \in f^{-1}(U)$, $f(x) \in U$, and thus $y \in U$. $\Box$

Coming back to *proposition 1*:

Suppose there exists $U \subseteq Y$ such that $f(f^{-1}(U)) ≠ U$. By lemma 1, we know that $$f\big(f^{-1}(U)\big) \subseteq U\,.$$ Hence, it must be the case that $$U \not\subseteq f\big(f^{-1}(U)\big)\,.$$ Then we can take some $y \in U$, such that there is no $x \in f^{-1}(U)$ with $f(x) = y$. But that means that there is no $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$. And since $U \subseteq Y$, $y \in Y$, which means that $f$ is not surjective. $\Box$

---

1. Is it correct?
2. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: I haven't looked at your proof but the statement is actually a biconditional.  There is also a dual version.  
$$\ $$
**Proposition 1.**  For a function $f:X\to Y$ from a set $X$ to another set $Y$, $f$ is a surjection if and only if, for all $V\subseteq Y$, $f\big(f^{-1}(V)\big)=V$.
$$\ $$
**Proposition 1'.** For a function $f:X\to Y$ from a set $X$ to another set $Y$, $f$ is an injection if and only if, for all $U\subseteq X$, $f^{-1}\big(f(U)\big)=U$.$$\ $$ ***Update.***  I looked at the proof.  It is good.

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: The proof is fine. Just use $\nsubseteq$ instead of $\subsetneq$ and maybe one should explain the deduction of "But that means that there is no $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$" a bit more.

Comment: After the subset has changed, this looks OK.  The end of the proof is not as tight as it could be.  Depending on the expected level of detail, there might be a slight jump in getting to $f$ is not surjective.  To tighten it, I would suggest summarizing the important facts at the end.